# Configuration for scaling Grpc Server for blocking calls

Tags: java, netty, grpc, grpc-java

I was learning GRPC as we are planning to expose GRPC server (instead of Rest Endpoint) within spring boot microservice which will be listening on dedicated port. I am using following code snippet to create GRPC server.

```java
io.grpc.Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
        .addService(new MyServiceImpl())
        .build()
        .start();
```

Here server object which is encapsulating unerlying NettyServerBuilder object is being initialized with default values. We are planning to deploy it in production (**powerful hardware**) where we are expecting huge traffic (approxy **10k calls per second**) from the grpc clients. My question is like For scaling  How should I configure underlying NettyServerBuilder. Which are the important configs that I need to tune? Any suggestions and best practices are welcome

Answer (score 3):

You should:

1. Use `serverBuilder.executor()` and set a `ForkJoinPool` as the executor.   This executor is where the gRPC Callbacks (i.e. the methods on `ServerCall.Listener`) are invoked.   ForkJoinPool is a heavily optimized, more concurrent executor, and allows the network threads to get back to handling things like HTTP/2 and SSL.
2. Use `nettyServerBuilder.workerEventLoopGroup()` and provide an `EpollEventLoopGroup`.  This allows you to use an optimized network thread implementation that is more efficient than the default Nio Java network implementation.  The number of threads you provide to the group will depend on your benchmarks, but a good rule of thumb is 2-4 workers.  gRPC uses EventLoops somewhat differently than netty, so you don't usually need 1 per core.
3. Use [netty-tcnative](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative) for your SSL implementation.  It is a enormously faster SSL implementation that wraps OpenSSL and BoringSSL.

We try hard to make the default implementation of gRPC's server to be fast without any extra configuration, so even if you don't use these, it's still going to be pretty fast.